# How to rotate element on mousewheel using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I want when I mouse up the box rotates infinitely and mouse down too 
but when I make it it just rotates from `20` to `-20` degrees. How can I make this?

https://jsfiddle.net/eunjin/n4ckfxw2/1/

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        $(".box").animate({ rotate: 20 }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'); 
                $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
                $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".box").animate({ rotate: -20 }, {
            step: function(now, fx){
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'); 
                $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
                $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a variable and store rotate value in it. On `mousewheel` event change it and animate element to target value.

```
var rotate = 0;
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){       
    // Increase/decrease value of rotate
    rotate += e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 20 : -20;
    // Animate rotate of element
    $(".box").stop().animate({rotate:rotate},{
        step:function(now){
            $(this).css({
                '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+ now +'deg)',            
                '-moz-transform':'rotate('+ now +'deg)',
                'transform':'rotate('+ now +'deg)'
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

```js
var rotate = 0;
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){ 
  rotate += e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 20 : -20;
  $(".box").stop().animate({rotate:rotate},{
    step:function(now){
      $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)',            
        '-moz-transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)',
        'transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)'
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body { 
    padding: 10px 100px 10px 100px 
}
.box {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px;  
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can test result properly in [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jp38otfv/)